# Bitwise operations on constants within Class not working as expected

Tags: python, class, constants, bit-manipulation

I'm trying to do some bitwise operations on some constants within a class and for some reason, the computed value is not being stored.

Here's what I'm doing:

```
class FramePacket(object):
    def __init__(self,frame):
        self._frame = frame

    def create_packet(self):

        # Frame ID
        FRAME_ID = 0x7

        # Commands
        CMD_PING = 0x0
        CMD_STORE = 0x1
        CMD_PLAY = 0x2
        CMD_DEMO = 0x3
        CMD_CLEAR = 0xE
        CMD_WIPE = 0xF

        f_data = (FRAME_ID << 4) + CMD_STORE
        print "f_data  ---> " + str(f_data)
```

When I execute this, I get an error and see this in the traceback:

```
    print "f_data  ---> " + str(f_data)
NameError: name 'f_data' is not defined
```

However, when I execute this in the Python interpreter, without using a class, it works as expected:

```
>>> CMD_STORE = 0x1
>>> FRAME_ID = 0x7
>>> f_data = (FRAME_ID << 4) + CMD_STORE
>>> print "f_data  ---> " + str(f_data)
f_data  ---> 113
```

I'm missing something but not sure what...

Thanks.

Comment: Nothing wrong with this code. Probably an indent issue putting the print statement on the wrong scope (outside the function)

Comment: @lcfseth  Winner winner chicken dinner.   That was it.  I'm using Sublime Text 2 and still didn't notice it.  I deleted the whitespace and re-indented and now it works as expected.   Thank you!

Comment: Sublime text 2 is best, how could miss it :p Good luck with your coding!